# 4D data in Cesium

Tags: interface, visualization, cesiumjs, temporal

I'm working on a project with hourly data for some buildings of different areas. 
I have asked this question is the Cesium forum, but got no answer. 
Check link [Here](https://groups.google.com/forum/embed/?place=forum/cesium-dev&showsearch=true&showpopout=true&hideforumtitle=true&fragments=true&parenturl=https%3A%2F%2Fcesiumjs.org%2Fforum.html#!searchin/cesium-dev/4d/cesium-dev/5ZYF7JcgPmI/kR9skjpYBQAJ).

The idea is that I need to represent these data sets in CZML.
The data has different values for each hour of the year of each building. 
these values are energy kilowatt values.

To explain it further:
Each building, has an energy value, that changes every hour.
Different buildings will have different values for the same hour!

So an example: 
for A building I have the following: 
"hour_1" : 0.0, "hour_2" : 0.0, "hour_3" : 0.0, "hour_4" : 0.0, "hour_5" : 0.0, "hour_6" : 0.0, "hour_7" : 0.0, "hour_8" : 0.0, "hour_9" : 1.0, "hour_10" : 29.1265, "hour_11" : 55.0334, "hour_12" : 68.0527

I need the "color" to change for each building, at each hour depending on the value it has in the attribute table.
Is it possible to be represented in CZML data? 
or what other alternatives can be used with Cesium?

Thank you in advance.

-Ayah

Comment: Seems like you've got some answers from the forum now.  Do you still need this question open?

Comment: No thank you, this question has been solved